# Is it possible to update only css using ajax without refreshing the tags and how?

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

Is there any way to update only page content styles  using php or ajax without refreshing the content? Content here i mean the html tags and its contents except the styles defined for it. The styles should come from an css and should be linked to tags using classnames and ids.

If possible, anyone please specify a hint or way to accomplish this. it is preferred that only using php/ajax and css not other languages like javacsript or jQuery.

I know how to achieve this with jQuery and javascript.

In short, I need to update the css of the html tags only(but not the tags), using ajax or php dynamically. Is it possible? If any, let me please know how?

PHP and AJAX  are the languages I would be using to show the content and later on AJAX would be used to update the content. PHP could be used to update or identify the class names,stylesheet etc.

Comment: AJAX _is_ JavaScript (AJAX = Asynchronous **JavaScript** And XML), and jQuery isn't a language.

Comment: Not really. The css files are read by the browser itself, you only define the location. But you can control the caching value and lifetime, but that won't help you here. Sorry.

Comment: ya i know. here i mean't that i need a solution from the server side, not from the client side. so we could use AJAX,PHP but not with simple Javascript.I need the page to communicate with the server to update the styles without loading the page or contents. :)

Comment: why again a down vote? can you please leave a comment explaining what's wrong with the question? i would appreciate to know if any :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to dynamically change the stylesheet without reloading the page, you will **have** to use JavaScript.

### For the simplest answer, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2090682/2624391) on SO:

> Add an `id` attribute to the CSS link tag to manipulate the tag using JavaScript:
>
> ```
> <link id="cssfile" href="css/avocado.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
> ```
>
> The Javascript to set the href attribute resembles:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('cssfile').href = 'css/carrot.css';
> ```
>
> Colours could be tweaked by the user, by clicking a link:
>
> ```
> <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('cssfile').href='css/carrot.css';">Carrots</a>
> ```
>
> By changing the media type, this could also allow users to quickly change print layouts, the preferred layout on mobiles (or tablets), and more.
>
> This solution does not require jQuery.

[This website](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml) also has a good script you can use. It adds a bit more complexity and the feature to save the stylesheet a user's using in a cookie

### If you're using jQuery, you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/intesso/jquery-getCSS)

This plugin is meant to mimic jQuery's jQuery.get() AJAX call and is as simple to use as

```
 $.getCSS("getCSS.css");
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/intesso/jquery-getCSS) for more info.

---

Additionaly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2090829/2624391) SO answer is a **very** good resource, and provides a step by step tutorial on how to create a dynamic style sheet switcher.

Comment: Thank u :) but, here plain javascript is used. i want to achieve this with ajax. i mean the class name,id could be changed or the stylesheet could be modified and shown the updated styles without refreshing the page or with an ajax trigger, not with a javascript event.

Comment: But AJAX ***is*** JavaScript. Anyways, see my edit as I give a couple different solutions, and make sure you check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090657/how-do-i-switch-external-css-files-with-ajax) on SO.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.

AJAX is not a new programming language, but a new way to use existing standards.

AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.(http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

I think you confused in using javsScript and jquery ,but you can use  `($(document).ready(function(){}); or ($(function(){ });` , to catch up any events and make change accordingly .

Comment: i know it dear. I just want it to be updated from the server side, if any. :)

Comment: it will be updated according to the result comes from server side